# Parsing Comma Separated File in C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to parse a file in C that is a comprised of sets of numbers (one per line). Each set is separated by a comma. For some reason I'm getting an incorrect output.

Example input: 1,2,4,8,55,777
Output: A bunch of what seem to be memory addresses. And when I print off the strings it's not reading 55 or 777 (or any number over two digits).

```
int * parseFile(char *input, int *set, int line)
{
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    char *token = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    int i;

    FILE *f = fopen(input, "r");

    for (i = 1; i < line; i++)
        fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, f);

    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE); // Clear the buffer.
    i = 0;

    if (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, f) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(buf, ",");
        set[i] = atoi(token);
        i++;

       while (set[i] != 0) {
            printf("%d\n", set[i]);
            set[i] = atoi(token);
            i++;

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    return set;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic - what's the point of the first `for` loop?

Comment: To read in whatever lines before the line which you'd like to read (specified by the parameter line).

Comment: You are putting twice the first value in array (in position 0 and 1)

Comment: Okay, then how are `set` and `BUF_SIZE` defined?

Comment: Off-topic: you ALWAYS should check the result of fopen().

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fscanf()`

use the following `fscanf()` into a loop till you reach the end of the file:

```
int a,b,c,d,e,x;
while (fscanf(f, " %d , %d , %d , %d, %d , %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &x) != EOF) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value of set[i] before you assign to it the value of atoi.
Consider:

```
set[i] = atoi(token);
printf("%d,",set[i]); 

while (set[i] != 0) {
    i++;
    set[i] = atoi(token);
    printf("%d,",set[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused with this:

```
set[i] = atoi(token); //i = 0
i++; //i = 1

while (set[i] != 0) { //set[1] = ???
  printf(...set[i]); 
  set[i] = atoi(token);
  i++;
  ...
```

so, depending on the previous content of the array "set", you decide, whether to read the next value. So, if you did a "memset(set, 0, sizeof(set));" you actually read one line. If you did not clear the "set", if may contain rubbish, which you "printf()" before readin the next value

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I wasn't setting the integer array to all zeroes before hand and I was reading in the first token twice.

Answer (score 0):

I like this

```
 if (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, f) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(buf, ",");
    for (i=0; token != NULL; i++) {
      set[i] = atoi(token);
      // Optional: if (set[i] == 0) break; // I don't know why to stop on 0
      printf("%d\n", set[i]);
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
  }
```

The break is a little ugly, but it's better than

for (i=0; (token != NULL) && ((set[i] = atoi(token)) != 0); i++) {